# Excel does not indicate right values from HTML table from Web Query

Tags: html, excel, html-table

I never 'coded' with Excel. So I do not have a code that shows my problem. But as you will see it is a very basic problem and can be reproduced very fast. I am trying right now to implement an HTML table in Excel, which should be fairly simple. But the result is not showing the right value.

1. Go on https://coinmarketcap.com/#EUR and copy the link.
2. I open an Excel file, go on Data > From Web > an insert the [URL](https://coinmarketcap.com/#EUR) and press Ok and Load Table.

Unfortunately, the table shows now the values in US currency and not in EURO which is pre-selected in the URL. Can someone tell me why this happens and how to display the EURO values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit I see now that the source is written in USD and there is a conversion table at the bottom of the source.
`data-eur="1.1268405531885644"` I guess USD times that equals to euro. 
It's possible to use this method but it depends on what you are trying to do.
End of edit;

Maybe you can try and "download" the source of the page an manipulate the data from there?

EDIT 2;
It seems it was harder than I thought.
You need to use the get from web, but I made a conversion macro that will grab the conversion rate used on the page and update all the prices on the table.
Since you asked for Euro currency I assume you are European, your profile does not give any clues either.
But that means I made the macro to suit European version of Excel where you use `,` as fraction separator.
If this is incorrect it's an easy fix.

Open Excel and press ALT+ F11.
Insert -> Module.
Big white "notepad" opens on your right.
Paste the code below  in the window.
Close the VBA editor.
Save the workbook as Excel file with macro .xlsm
Do the web query and place it in A1. Or at least in A-column.
In Excel Ribbon menu, View, and all the way to the right "Macro".
Run Euro.

Hopefully that should do it.

```
Sub euro()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim HTML As String
    Dim REeuro As Object
    Set REeuro = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    'ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    HTML = GetHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/")
    REeuro.Pattern = "data-eur=\" & Chr(34) & "(\d+\.\d+)"
    REeuro.Global = True
    REeuro.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = REeuro.Execute(HTML)


    EuroConversion = Matches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    FirstRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        Range("C" & i).Value = Mid(Range("C" & i).Value, 2) / EuroConversion
        Range("D" & i).Value = Mid(Range("D" & i).Value, 2) / EuroConversion
        Range("F" & i).Value = Mid(Range("F" & i).Value, 2) / EuroConversion

    Next i

    'Columns("C:F").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

End Sub


Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
       .Open "GET", URL, False
       .Send
        GetHTML = .ResponseText
    End With
End Function
```

What if it does not work...

Go back to VBA editor (Alt + F11) and check the references.
I use these in the image.
[image]

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your fast help. Could you maybe elaborate a second how to 'run' this code. Since I never did something like that with Excel?

Comment: @xm0riTzx Sure. Is it one specific value you want or is it the full table?

Comment: @ Andreas: I want the entire table. I think what you posted above shoudl do it. I will try it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ Andreas: Hey, there is one more thing. I am usually using Excel in a US setting; therefore I am using "." instead of "," as decimal separator. Could you tell me how to fix that as you said above it's an 'easy' fix?

Comment: @xm0riTzx Do you use ","  as tousands separator just as on the webpage? And your Excel "knows" how to handle it? So `=1,000*1.2` does not create an error if you type that in a cell?

Comment: @ Andreas: It tells me type mismatch in the following line

"Range("D" & i).Value = Mid(Replace(Replace(Range("D" & i).Value, ",", ""), ".", ","), 2) / Replace(EuroConversion, ".", ",")"

Comment: @xm0riTzx No, I mean really. Go to Excel and input =1,000*1.2 in a cell if it outputs 1,200 then all is good. I just want to make sure we don't end up in another error.

Comment: Ok! Just a sec I need to get my son in bed. Back in 10 minutes or so...

Comment: @xm0riTzx I updated my answer now. Just copy paste the code. I have also added another line that is commented. It's the green line (you will see it when you copypaste it) at the top-ish. It will update the data table. If you wish to do that automatically just delete the `'` and it will update the table at the same time as it converts to euro. Also I commented out the line with numberformat as I'm not sure if that is correct for you. Try it the way it is now and see what you think. Note that I have to remove the euro sign to calculate the conversion, but it can be added if you want it.

Comment: just not sure what that will do with the format of the sheets. Excel is a bit "special" about that. When you add text to numbers and all that.

Answer (score 0):

@ Andreas: Thanks for your effort!!! Unfortunately, the numbers are not really correct. The Euro rate should be around 2500 for Bitcoins but its 744 after the conversion. But regarding format everything is fine now. There was also an error message. Its called "Runtype Error '13' Type Mismatch" :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a message about this post. First off. Try to step through the code and see what the Euroconversion-variable is set to. Step through by pushing F8 and you will se a yellow marker. Each click on F8 makes one line of code run. So click F8 til the line is at "LastRow = ...." and move the mouse to "Euroconversion" above. A "box" should appear with the number.